# Is it possible to setup RAID10 and RAID1 (on spare space) with 4 HDDs with 2 different sizes?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, raid, nas, raid-1

I have NAS setup with 2x 8TB and 2x 2TB drives.. Is it possible to setup RAID10 with 4TB of usable space (2TB used from each drive) and for the other 6TB in 8TB drives, setup RAID1? Do you just need to partition 8TB drive with 2TB and 6TB volumes? Is it even a good idea?

Comment: You can use different size drives but the partitions used by the RAID have to be the same size.  Using multiple drive partitions for multiple RAID arrays is a horrible idea.  RAID arrays are normally used so a single hdd failing doesn't mean the RAID is lost.  But if the same drive is used for multiple arrays then multiple arrays will be lost depending on the situation

Comment: This entirely possible using linux MDRAID.  I usually do not run 2 raids on a given device; rather 1 RAID then simply partition the additional free space.  But it is absolutely possible in general; its just a matter of what your NAS lets you do.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you can do this will depend on your NAS - but to the extent they are backed of Linux (or similar) and MDADM, this is quite doable.

Of-course, a better way to do this would be to either deploy ZFS or to have the 2 8TB drives set up with RAID1, the 2 2TB drives set up with RAID1, and then use LVM to combine this into a single large disk - in this way you are effectively RAID10'ing the whole system without concerning yourself with the different disk sizes.